# Solution to get individual value passed to each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have an array of values:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I want to select all `a` tags on the page and assign them their respective href values from inside of the array.

```
var $a = $('a');
```

I ran a for loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  a.attr('href', arr[i])
}
```

The loop will give ALL href the value of 5...I understand why it is this way but I can't think of a solution to get: 1st href = 1, 2nd href = 2, 3rd href = 3.....etc. What is the solution? Thank you.

Comment: `a[i].href = arr[i]`?

Comment: is the anchor tags count and `arr` array elements counts are the same?

Comment: yes, they are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to target the respective *anchor* element in each iteration. You can use jQuery's [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) with the current value of *i*.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var $a = $('a');
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $a.eq(i).attr('href', arr[i]);
  $a.eq(i).text('Link ' +arr[i]); // for test
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
```

Though I prefer using jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) which uses *this* object to refer the current element:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$('a').each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('href', arr[i]);
  $(this).text('Link ' +arr[i]); // for test
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `a` variable contain all anchor tags so you should select relevant element by index using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) in loop

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var a = $("a");
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  a.eq(i).attr('href', arr[i])
}
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var a = $("a");
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  a.eq(i).attr('href', arr[i])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">1th</a>
<a href="">2th</a>
<a href="">3th</a>
<a href="">4th</a>
<a href="">5th</a>
```

You can simplify your code and use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of `for` to looping.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$("a").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('href', arr[i]);
});
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$("a").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('href', arr[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">1th</a>
<a href="">2th</a>
<a href="">3th</a>
<a href="">4th</a>
<a href="">5th</a>
```

Also you can do this work using pure javascript

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((ele, i) => ele.href = arr[i])
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((ele, i) => ele.href = arr[i])
```

```html
<a href="">1th</a>
<a href="">2th</a>
<a href="">3th</a>
<a href="">4th</a>
<a href="">5th</a>
```